# Pytorch - Handling in place operation for sequence to sequence Multi-dimensional LSTM layer

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, in-place

I am trying to implement a sequence to sequence LSTM layer in Pytorch. Here a sequence can be of higher dimension than 1 (an image is a sequence, it just has 2 indexes that increase instead of one). More information [in the following paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.2011).

The `forward()` function of my network is:

```py
def forward(self, x):
    """ Note: x is of shape (d1, ..., dn, batch_size, input_size). """
    dimensions = x.shape[:-2]
    batch_size = x.shape[-2]
    f = torch.empty(self.dim_in, *dimensions, batch_size, self.size_out)
    i = torch.empty(*dimensions, batch_size, self.size_out)
    o = torch.empty(*dimensions, batch_size, self.size_out)
    c = torch.empty(*dimensions, batch_size, self.size_out)
    s = torch.empty(*dimensions, batch_size, self.size_out)
    h = torch.empty(*dimensions, batch_size, self.size_out)
    for idx in self.iter_idx(dimensions):
        # 1/ Forget, input, output and cell activation gates.
        for l in range(self.dim_in):
            f[l][idx] = torch.sigmoid(self.biasf[l] + torch.mm(x[idx], self.wf[l]) + sum(torch.mul(h[prev(idx,k)], self.uf[l][k]) for k in np.nonzero(idx)[0]))
        i[idx] = torch.sigmoid(self.biasi + torch.mm(x[idx], self.wi) + sum(torch.mul(h[prev(idx,k)], self.ui[k]) for k in np.nonzero(idx)[0]))
        o[idx] = torch.sigmoid(self.biaso + torch.mm(x[idx], self.wo) + sum(torch.mul(h[prev(idx,k)], self.uo[k]) for k in np.nonzero(idx)[0]))
        c[idx] = torch.sigmoid(self.biasc + torch.mm(x[idx], self.wc) + sum(torch.mul(h[prev(idx,k)], self.uc[k]) for k in np.nonzero(idx)[0]))
        # 2/ cell state
        s[idx] = torch.tanh(torch.mul(i[idx], c[idx]) + sum(torch.mul(f[k][idx], s[prev(idx,k)]) for k in np.nonzero(idx)[0]))
        # 3/ Final output
        h[idx] = torch.mul(o[idx], s[idx])
    return h
```

When I try to run it and the `backward()` method of the loss is called, the following error is thrown:

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [32, 3]], which is output 0 of SelectBackward, is at version 100; expected version 99 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

The backtrace points to this specific line:

```py
s[idx] = torch.tanh(torch.mul(i[idx], c[idx]) + sum(torch.mul(f[k][idx], s[prev(idx,k)]) for k in np.nonzero(idx)[0]))
```

From what I understand, Pytorch is angry at me because I modified the tensor `s` in place. Looking at the error message, I see `version 100` and expected `version 99`, which implies the error is thrown when computing the gradient for the last iteration of the loop and Pytorch expected to have `s` at a version ine loop iteration prior.

For me it shouldn't be an issue, because this loop merely "initializes" `s` (and the other tensors too). But I understand that the interpreter may have a hard time determining this statically.

So I have 3 questions:

- why `s` specifically? It is neither the first nor the last tensor to be modified in place during the loop.
- is there a way to tell Pytorch that I am just filling the arrays? Or to tell him to only look at the last version for gradient computation?
- is there a way to rewrite this code without in place operations? I tried a version where `f`, `i`, `o`, etc are lists that grow with the loop, but I get the same error on lines like `s = torch.cat((s,s_tmp), axis=0)`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I cannot answer your question but maybe this might help with matrix multiplications, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952700/multiplying-two-3d-pytorch-tensors-iteratively